# C++ FillArray вызвано исключение

Tags: c++

я новенький в изучении C++. Что в этом коде может быть не так?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;



void fillArray(int* const arr, const int size)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

     arr[i] = rand() % 15;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         cout << arr[i] << endl;
     }
   }
} 

int main()
{
int a = 3;
int size = 4;

fillArray(&a, size);


}
```

Comment: В этом коде не так отсутствие массива.

Comment: В этом коде не хватает того, что называется [mcve].

Comment: @älёxölüt, разве?

Comment: Какой size = 4, когда ваш size равен еденице. Поставьте 1 - и ошибка уйдёт. Вот в чём ошибка. Если не понятно - то ставьте квадратные скобки и в них пишите ту же цифру что при size - и тему массивы в с++ - выучить.

Comment: @älёxölüt, ну всё же верно ответил. Нет массива - держи проблемы)

Comment: @älёxölüt, Qwertiy уже не то(р)т…

Comment: Я считаю что такие вопросы нужно закрывать, как вопросы вызваные ошибкой опечаткой, и не несут полезности. То что кому-то лень почитать и понять раздел массивы - не должно наполнять базу SO. Даже наличие ответов на такие вопросы - их колличество не уменьшит. Ответ верный, хоть и спорный

Comment: @Qwertiy да. Код не минимален, и сообщения об ошибке не приведено.

Comment: @älёxölüt, при UB сообщение об ошибке может быть любое. А то и вовсе никакого.

Comment: @Qwertiy у ТС вполне конкретная ситуация, написано "вызвано исключение". Будь добр привести текст.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема тут в передачи в функцию неверного количества элементов, на которые указывает указатель `arr`. В записи `&a` `arr` будет указывать на 1 элемент, соответственно `size` должен быть равен `1`, а не `4`.